# not authorized to make purchases of this in app in sandbox at this time

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I got the below error for sandbox testing...How to avoid this error:-
you are not authorized to make purchases of this in app in sandbox at this time

Comment: @Till Thanks for the reply..What should i configure in the application to avoid this error?

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: @xus its because of the sandbox server...

Comment: in my case it was because I was using a wrong (deleted) iTunes Connect test user

Comment: +1 IMHO this is a real question with a valid answer by @xus appearing in one of the comments (close may have been unwarranted).

Comment: Poorly worded, but an incredibly important question. What do you do to debug when you get that error.